# How many object created when creating object of String

Tags: java, string, object

Actually I am bit confused that how many object created in below "code processing".

```
String s=new String("A");
s=s+"B";
```

Actually someone said that here 4 objects will be created but in whole processing but how not understand.

Please anyone can give me detail description also included memory part such string pool etc.

Comment: This looks like a certification question ;) did you pass?

Comment: I'm guessing `String s = new String` is one, `"A"` is another, `"B"` is one and the concatenation operator `+` will create the fourth

Comment: Not a direct duplicate since this asks how many `objects` created, which presumably can include `StringBuilder` also as per other's comments below.

Comment: @vikingsteve - Its like running in a never-ending loop. The StringBuilder is again supported (backed) by  a char array and other things.

Comment: @vikingsteve,Actually I said three objects. But I don't know anything that String s=new String("ABC"); creating two objects. That's was the mistaken point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `String` literal Objects, namely `"A"` and `"B"`. Then you explicitly instantiate a new instance of "A" with `new String("A");`. Finally, the fourth instance is created when you perform the `String` concatenation `s+"B"`

Comment: The StringBuilder behind s + "B"?

Comment: @TheLostMind Either a StringBuilder instance, or some other instance `s+"B"` will yield a new instance of `String` (and may well instantiate a new `StringBuilder`). If we counted the character array in each `String` instance we could get even more `Object` instances.

Comment: Probably you are right.. In this case, the array supporting StringBuilder must also count and also the length of String changes things. But 4 is *accessible* number of objects. :P

Answer (score 6):

- The first `String` created is literal `"A"`, that is, if not interned
  prior.
- The second `String` is the instance generated by the `new` keyword.
- The third one is literal `"B"`, again, if not interned prior.
- The last one is the concatenation of `s` and `"B"`.

Comment: Correct. worth noting is that the `new String()` around `"A"` is superfluous.

Comment: @vikingsteve absolutely. I also agree this looks like a 1Z0-803 question, as you mention in the comment :)

Comment: There will also be A StringBuilder object created. Total 5 objects

Comment: @vikingsteve Not necessarily. `"A" == "A"` but `"A" != new String("A")`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is superfluous if you know how to compare `String` equality, through `String.equals`. The only valid usage of `new` with `String`s is when you are converting from an encoding to another in my opinion.

Comment: @TheLostMind really? Cool, I never knew that. Awesome.

Comment: @vikingsteve `<sarcasm/>`? XD

Comment: @TheLostMind @Mena sorry, I was genuinely not being sarcastic, I meant that I `did` learn something new today - so thank you, honestly!

Comment: @vikingsteve no need to apologize, personally I'm actually totally ok with sarcasm (especially when not directed at me ;). OK with non-sarcasm as well though :P